How significant is COHP for ionic inorganic material?
For ionic materials such as NaCl, Li2O, MgO, metal atoms Li, Na, Mg donate their electrons to Cl, O. The electron overlapping between positive ions (Li, Mg) and anions is small. Does this mean COHP has no meaning and COHP shouldn't be considered for these strong ionic compounds?

Does COHP means Crystal Orbital Hamilton Populations?

yes, it does. Crystal Orbital Hamilton Populations is COHP.
